# Why does this code only work when the isNaN is put last?

Tags: javascript

So I have just started with Codecademy learning JS when I got to a task that required me to write a function that takes an input and evaluates whether or not it is even. I was also required to use `isNaN` to determine whether the input was a number.

Anyway, I have two codes which I thought should have worked however only one did.The only difference is the order of the statements. I was just wondering if anyone can tell me why only one code works?

Code one (works):

```
isEven = function(number){
if(number%2 === 0){
  return true;
}
else if(number%2 === 1){
  return false;
}
else if(isNaN(number)){
  return('Please enter a number');
}
```

However, this one doesn't:

```
isEven = function(number){
if(isNaN(number)){
  return('Please enter a number')
}
else if(number%2 === 1){
  return false;
}
else if(number%2 === 0){
  return true;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how the order of the if/else if statements affects the code?

Comment: The two version work the same for me (after adding the missing closing braces). In what way is the second one not working?

Comment: Check your console (f12) for errors. They should work the same.

Comment: You are missing brackets...in last one

Comment: @Techsin *I know a couple of '}' are missing*

Comment: I tested the second one and it worked for me? what test numbers/values are you using?

Comment: I am also wondering what test value you used. Both functions should be working equivalent. The order does in this case not affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not complete

try this:

```
isEven = function(number){
  if(isNaN(number)){
return('Please enter a number')
  }else if(number%2 === 1){
  return false;
  }else if(number%2 === 0){
  return true;
 }
}
```

You were missing last two '}'.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the isNaN funky behavior it has sometimes.  For example isNaN('') returns false even though an empty string is not a number...

isNaN(null) also returns false even though null is not a number...

Answer (score 0):

Correct the second function as following:

```
isEven = function(number){
  if(isNaN(number)){
    return('Please enter a number');
  }
  else if(number%2 === 1){
    return false;
  }
  else if(number%2 === 0){
    return true;
  }
}
```

In 2nd code,

1. You missed ';' in end of return('Please enter a number')
2. End of function at the end.

I have corrected and its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
isEven = function(number){
  if (number % 2 === 0){
return "string1";
  }else if(NaN(number)){
return("Not a number");
  }else {
return "string3";
  } 
};
isEven(12);
```

I used NaN instead of isNaN - and it completed successfully!